# Why is this http post request in AngularJS giving an unexpected token error?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am able to successfully do an HTTP post request using the following

```
curl --request POST
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"},"subject": "Hey","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Test"}]}'
```

I tried to convert that to an angular HTTP request by doing

```
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
                 headers: {
                    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx'
                },
                data: '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"},"subject": "Hey","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Test"}]}'
            }).
            success(function(data, status) {}).
            error(function(data, status) {});
```

I'm getting an unexpected token error on the `Authorization: Bearer` line.

Answer (score 1):

the headers object should be a key/value object:

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxx'}
```

Comment: hmm, you are fast, dint notice your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to have `'` after  `'Authorization'`

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxx'}
```

**Request:**

```
 $http({method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
        headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        data: '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "xxx@yahoo.com"},"subject": "Hey","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Test"}]}'
        }).
        success(function(data, status) {}).
        error(function(data, status) {});
```